# Infinite scroll of images?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, vb.net, webforms

ASP.NET VB.

I have a function **fGetGridImagesHTML**() that returns a **String** of HTML markup of a whole lot of images. E.g.:

```
<div class='dvImage'>
    <img alt='photo' id='Img7' src='http://mysite.../cf62876.png' class='imgStandard'></img>
</div>

<div class='dvImage'>
    <img alt='photo' id='Img8' src='http://mysite.../yg87678.png' class='imgStandard'></img>
</div>

<div class='dvImage'>
    <img alt='photo' id='Img9' src='http://mysite.../uj09598.png' class='imgStandard'></img>
</div>

'etc
```

I currently have it called from a default.aspx page:

```
<div id="dvGrid01">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldLastRowNumberRetrieved" runat="server" Value="0" />
    <%=fGetGridImagesHTML()%>
</div>
```

There may be up to around 2,000+ images.

I only want to initially display the first 100 images, then when the user scrolls down I want a loading gif to appear and it to load the next 100 images.

I have the backend SQL database now accepting:

```
@EnterGetAfterRow bigint,
@EnterNumberOfRows bigint
```

and it only returns a selection of table rows in order accordingly.

Can anyone help with what code would be needed to add to the default.aspx page to accomplish the infinite-scroll behavior as mentioned above?

Thanks for any help with any Javascript code or whatever is needed.

TIA 
Mark